# Wine doesn't support 32 bit audio editing

Tags: sound, wine, audio-recording

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3 LTS with WineHQ 6.0.1 (to run old MS-Windows native software).

When I use the old (but still so good) Adobe Audition 1.5, I cannot to use 32 bit audio.

I mean, If I converted some audio piece from 16 bit to 32 bit, I just get white noise.

Of course, it is not something related with Ubuntu Studio system because I can use 32 bit audio, so fine, with Audacity and other Linux native apps.

I wonder if this is a WineHQ limitations, or something is wrong with my installation parameters.

Any idea?

Comment: Check https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2538 .

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you so much for your data!!! Now I know it is an issue between Wine and Adobe Audition 1.5. Absolutely, not my system. Thanks!!!